# It seems my downloads are stuck at a certain percentage and never seem to complete in Firefox

Tags: firefox, 15.04, downloads

I have a screenshot below of where my downloads seem to be stuck:

[image]

As with this picture taxati.deb has been stuck at 55 seconds remaining and 220 KB/sec for a few hours

This happens with most of my downloads and I'm honestly getting frustrated due to the lack of downloads on my Ubuntu.

Comment: Does Google Chrome work?

Comment: @Tim Google Chrome on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, or Chromium.

Comment: I'm going to try downloading chromium through the webstore (which downloads programs fully and efficiently) and try downloading from there

Comment: Okay, report back when you have tried :)

Comment: Just tried Chromium and it does not seem to work

Comment: As in not work at all or not download files?

Comment: try https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/downthemall/ ... stock downloader sucks... this one apart from other things, can reconnect (and it works)...

Comment: @MichalHagara That could solve it but unlikely as it affects Chrome too.

Comment: @Tim It downloads partially, just like the screenshot and does not seem to work.

Comment: @MichalHagara I'll give it a try

Comment: @MichalHagara This is very weird but it seems to work on Downthemall - Anyone care to explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala My guess is that you are losing packets, which is source of your problem in my opinion (you might want run some monitoring tool, for example wireshark) and DownthemAll is quicker and more succesfull in Retransmissioning... http://tdistler.com/2012/05/15/linux-detecting-dropped-network-packets

Comment: @MichalHagara Don't you think Wireshark is a bit of an overkill - Isn't there any way I analyse my packets through my terminal?

Comment: @MichalHagara + Even on Downthemall, It seems to go down to 0kb/s after a little while - However pausing and starting the download on Downthemall seems to get the download speed back up again

Comment: Please read this and try to monitor you packet loss: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-measure-network-latency-packet-loss-and-jitter-on-linux.html, to see, IF it is the problem... during testing download some random stuff

Comment: Or try http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/iperf-a-simple-but-powerful-tool-for-troubleshooting-networks/  I don't want to post unuseful answer... and monitor your network is task, you have to perform yourself anyway...

Comment: @MichalHagara Thank you for all the help anyways - I will get to the bottom of this problem and answer this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking my internet using the simple `ping google.com` command on my terminal, I learnt that I was experiencing about 3% data packet loss. I would suggest using the Firefox plugin 'Downthemall' or equivalent for Chrome. This way you can pause and restart your downloads when they stop receiving packets.

Thanks to all the help on the comments!

Comment: Great you found the answer, but I would go more to the depth of your problem! What is causing those packet losses? Probably Wifi card or Router. Try changing channels on your router, change range from 2.4 to 5 GHz . Are you experiencing packet loss even on wired connection?